# How to properly style mat-select-panels of two different <mat-select> form controls separately

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form with two mat-select form controls, as shown in the screenshots below. I added custom styling to the `mat-select-panel` for both form controls. The first screenshot shows that the `mat-select-panel` is properly aligned, but in the second screenshot for selecting units, the `mat-select-panel` is not properly aligned. I wanted to target the second form control specifically and style it, ensuring that the first form control would not be affected by the styling. I attempted to implement the following styling, but it was not applied to the second form control.

**HTML**

```
 ...
<mat-select class="units" formControlName="units" [value]="selectedUnits"
 ...
```

**SCSS**

```
::ng-deep  .units .mat-select-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]){
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Screenshot2**

[image]

**Styling**

```
::ng-deep  .mat-select-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]){
    margin-top: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    // margin-left: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="28px">
    <!-- Seller Field  -->
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
      <div fxLayout="row" class="label">
        <mat-label>{{ 'RECORD-SALE-MODAL.LABEL.SELLER' | transloco }}&nbsp;*
          <i *ngIf="!form.get('seller').errors?.required" class="cash-green seller-check-mark fa fa-check fa-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </mat-label>&nbsp;
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('seller').errors?.required"><i class="ml-189 fa fa-times fa-xs"></i>
        </mat-error>
      </div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-317">
        <mat-select formControlName="seller" placeholder="{{ 'RECORD-SALE-MODAL.PLACEHOLDER.SELLER' | transloco }}"
          required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let seller of sellers" [value]="seller" (click)="getSellerLots(seller)">
            {{seller.accountName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <!-- Units to sell Field  -->
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
      <div fxLayout="row" class="label">
        <mat-label>{{ 'RECORD-SALE-MODAL.LABEL.UNITS-FOR-SELL' | transloco }}&nbsp;*
          <i *ngIf="!form.get('units').errors?.required" class="units-check-mark cash-green fa fa-check fa-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </mat-label>&nbsp;
        <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('units').errors?.required"><i class="ml-395 fa fa-times fa-xs"></i>
        </mat-error>
      </div>
      
      <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" class="w-505" >
        <mat-select  formControlName="units" [value]="selectedUnits"
          placeholder="{{ 'RECORD-SALE-MODAL.PLACEHOLDER.UNITS-FOR-SELL' | transloco }}" required multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let unit of selectedUnits" [value]="unit">{{unit.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please replace w-505 this class with w-auto?

Comment: @AmanGojariya This  w-505 is based on the design requirements from UI/UX. I can't change it .

Comment: Ohh.. okay. I think this design issue with multiple selection dropdown. Can you please remove multiple just for checking design was fine without multiple selection?

Comment: @AmanGojariya I resolved the issue. I added a `panelClass` for each `mat-select ` and got rid of the `ng-deep` styling. I have explained this in the answer below.

Comment: @AmanGojariya by removing the multiple selection the mat-select panel gets aligned automatically as shown below

Answer (score 0):

After going through the [Angular material Select documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview). It's specified that we use the `panelClass` and add our custom css class for example. There is no need of using **ng-deep** (removed the ng-deep styling).

**1st Mat-Select**

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-317">
    <mat-select panelClass="record-sale-seller-select-panel" formControlName="seller" placeholder="{{ 'RECORD-SALE-MODAL.PLACEHOLDER.SELLER' | transloco }}"
      required>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let seller of sellers" [value]="seller" (click)="getSellerLots(seller)">
        {{seller.accountName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**2nd Mat-Select**

```
  <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" class="w-505" >
    <mat-select panelClass="record-sale-units-select-panel" formControlName="units" [value]="selectedUnits"
      placeholder="{{ 'RECORD-SALE-MODAL.PLACEHOLDER.UNITS-FOR-SELL' | transloco }}" required>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let unit of selectedUnits" [value]="unit">{{unit.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The custom css classes I have defined in the global styles file are (this is where i can style the mat-select-panels separately the way I want):

1. `record-sale-units-select-panel`
2. `record-sale-seller-select-panel`

**NOTE:** If you don't add the css classes styling in the global css file this will not work.

**Global css/scss**

```
//======================= Mat select panel styling =============//
.record-sale-units-select-panel {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-top: 48px;

}

.record-sale-seller-select-panel {
  background: rgba(81, 255, 0, 0.585);;
  margin-top: 48px;
  min-width: calc(80% + 120px) !important;
  margin-left: 30px !important;
}
```

### Result

[image]

[image]